# android client cant connect to pc server using kryonet

Tags: java, android, tcp, udp, kryonet

I'm trying to create a simple program to send data from my computer to my android app using the kryonet library. There is barely any documentation on how to create a working client for android. So far I think I have pieced together enough information from googling problems to get it working, but I still cant get it to connect. The stacktrace is telling me "java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to:..." but I know that my ip and port works because I've tested it with ssh.

Client side:

```
    public class bclient extends AppCompatActivity {
        Client client;
        String ip = "(my ip)";
        int tcpPort=2300, udpPort =2300;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shell);

        System.out.println("entering main activity");
        client=new Client();


        client.addListener(new Listener() {

            public void received(Connection c, Object p) {
                System.out.println("packets received!!");
                //check if packetmessage class matches
                if (p instanceof PacketMessage) {
                    //cast it, so we can access the message within
                    PacketMessage packet = (PacketMessage) p;
                    System.out.println("recieved a message from host: " + packet.message);

                }
            }

        });

        client.getKryo().register(PacketMessage.class);
        client.start();



        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    client.connect(5000, ip, tcpPort, udpPort);
                    System.out.println("connected!!!");
                } catch(IOException e) {

                    System.out.println("not connected :(");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
                return null;

            }
        }.execute(1);




    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_shell, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Packet class:

```
public class PacketMessage {
    public String message;
}
```

Server side:

```
public class aserver extends Listener{
     //create server
    static Server server;
    //ports to listen on
     static int udpPort = 2300;
    static int tcpPort= 2300;
    public static void main(String[]arg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Creating the server...");
        //create the server
        server = new Server();
        //register a packet
        server.getKryo().register(PacketMessage.class);
        //we can only send objects as packets if they are registered

        //bind the server
        server.bind(tcpPort, udpPort);
        //start the server
        server.start();
        //add the listener
        server.addListener(new aiserver());


        System.out.println("Server is operational!");
    }
    //this is run when a connection is received!
    public void connected(Connection c){
        System.out.println("recieved connection fron"+c.getRemoteAddressTCP().getHostString());
        //create a message packet.
        PacketMessage packetMessage = new PacketMessage();
        packetMessage.message= "Hello Frirend! The time is: "+new Date().toString();
        //send message
        //c.sendTCP(packetMessage);
        //Alternatively we could do:
        c.sendUDP(packetMessage);   
        //to send over UDP
    }
    //this is run when a client has received a packet
    public void recieved(Connection c, Object p){
        System.out.println("packet recieved by client!");
    }

    public void disconnected(Connection c){
        System.out.println("A client disconnected!");
    }

}
```